# Is the claim that Time doesn't exist defended among professionals today?

Tags: metaphysics, time, metaphilosophy

I think in philosophy of time Eternalism is the main option, Presentism the minority view, and there are some other theories I know almost nothing about like Growing block, or Moving spotlight.

But in the early 20. century serious philosophers like McTaggart or Bradley claimed time doesn't exist at all. Is it today still a serious view or has it been abandoned with the fall of Absolute idealism?

Comment: It is hard to tell any salient difference between McTaggart's "irreality" of time and B/C theory = eternalism. Especially when it is wedded to relativity where time is not an invariant, and hence not a genuine physical quantity. So it is still a major contender, only the prevailing verbiage has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Philpapers Survey offers a view on "what professionals think".  [About time](https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/4918): accept or lean to

A theory 27%
B theory  38 %
Alternative(s) 3.5 %
Agnostic 32 %